# How to implement recursion when defining a setf function?

Tags: common-lisp, setf

From the book "ANSI Common Lisp", p. 100 ch 6.1 :

*Suppose that a marble is a structure with a single field called color.
The function UNIFORM-COLOR takes a list of marbles and returns
their color, if they all have the same color, or nil if they have
different colors.
UNIFORM-COLOR is usable on a setf place in order to make the color
of each element of list of marbles be a specific color.*

```
(defstruct marble color)

(defun uniform-color (lst &optional (color (and lst (marble-color (car lst)))))
  (every #'(lambda (m) (equal (marble-color m) color)) lst))

(defun (setf uniform-color) (color lst)
  (mapc #'(lambda (m) (setf (marble-color m) color)) lst))
```

**How could you implement the `defun (setf uniform)` in a tail-recursive way instead of using the `mapc` applicative operator ?**

This question is specific to the case of `(defun (setf ...))`, it is not a question about how recursion or tail-recursion work in general.

Comment: I think it is not a good thing to define `setf` recursively for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you can just call setf recursively:

```
(defun (setf all-vals) (v ls)
  (when ls
    (setf (car ls) v)
    (setf (all-vals (cdr ls)) v)))

CL-USER> (let ((ls (list 1 2 3 4)))
           (setf (all-vals ls) :new-val)
           ls)
;;=> (:NEW-VAL :NEW-VAL :NEW-VAL :NEW-VAL)
```

this is how sbcl expands this:

```
(defun (setf all-vals) (v ls)
  (if ls
      (progn
       (sb-kernel:%rplaca ls v)
       (let* ((#:g328 (cdr ls)) (#:new1 v))
         (funcall #'(setf all-vals) #:new1 #:g328)))))
```

For the specific case of marbles:

```
(defun (setf uniform-color) (color lst)
  (when lst
    (setf (marble-color (car lst)) color)
    (setf (uniform-color (cdr lst)) color)))
```

Comment: Both this (v3) and the version in the book are pragmatically incorrect: `(setf <place> <value>)` should return `<value>`.  I suspect this is not formally required, so these are probably *technically* OK, but thee's no purpose in gratuitously violating expectations when it is trivial to not do so.

Answer (score 2):

#### General case

The answer is the same for `setf` functions and regular functions.
Let's say you have another function `f` that you want to call to print all the values in a list:

```
(defun f (list)
  (mapc 'print list))
```

You can rewrite it recursively, you have to consider the two distinct case of recursion for a list, either it is nil or a cons cell:

```
(defun f (list)
  (etypecase list
     (null ...)
     (cons ...)))
```

Typically in the `null` case (this is a type), you won't do anything.
In the general `cons` case (this is also a type), you have to process the first item and recurse:

```
(defun f (list)
  (etypecase list
    (null nil)
    (cons 
      (print (first list))
      (f (rest list)))))
```

The call to `f` is in tail position: its return value is the return value of the enclosing `f`, no other processing is done to the return value.

You can do the same with your function.

#### Note

It looks like the `setf` function defined in the book does not return the value being set (the color), which is bad practice as far as I know:

> all that is guaranteed is that the expansion is an update form that works for that particular implementation, that the left-to-right evaluation of subforms is preserved, and that the ultimate result of evaluating setf is the value or values being stored.

[5.1.1 Overview of Places and Generalized Reference](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_aa.htm)

Also, in your specific case you are subject to [5.1.2.9 Other Compound Forms as Places](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_abi.htm), which also says:

> A function named `(setf f)` must return its first argument as its only value in order to preserve the semantics of `setf`.

In other words `(setf uniform-color)` should return `color`.

But apart from that, the same section guarantees that a call to `(setf (uniform-color ...) ...)` *expands into a call to the function named `(setf uniform-color)`*, so it can be a recursive function too. This could have been a problem if this was implemented as macro that expands into the body of your function, but fortunately this is not the case.

#### Implementation

Setting all the colors in a list named `marbles` to `"yellow"` is done as follows:

```
(setf (uniform-color marbles) "yellow")
```

You can define `(setf uniform-color)` recursively by first setting the color of the first marble and then setting the color of the rest of the marbles.
A possible tail-recursive implementation that respects the semantics of `setf` is:

```
(defun (setf uniform-color) (color list)
  (if list
      (destructuring-bind (head . tail) list
        (setf (marble-color head) color)
        (setf (uniform-color tail) color))
      color))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but this does not answer my question which specifically address the `defun (setf ...)` case. I know how to do recursion and tail-recursion.